# Set background color/image for EKEventEditViewController

Tags: iphone, calendar, ekeventkit

The following is my code for adding a calendar event. I want to sent a background image for EKEventEditViewController.  I found this code

```
UITableView *eventTableView = [[editController.view subviews]objectAtIndex:0];
```

Using this code I was able to set background image for EKEventViewController but its not working for EKEventEditViewController.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

```
     EKEventEditViewController *editController = [[EKEventEditViewController alloc] init];
//    UITableView *eventTableView = [[editController.view subviews]objectAtIndex:0];
//    [eventTableView setHidden:YES];

//    [eventTableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
NSMutableArray *allViewControllers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: editController.viewControllers];
NSLog(@"%i", [allViewControllers count]);
 UITableView *eventTableView = [[[allViewControllers objectAtIndex:0] subviews] objectAtIndex:0];
//    UITableView *eventTableView = [[editController.view subviews]objectAtIndex:0];
//    eventTableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
UIColor *background = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"honeycomb.png"]];
eventTableView.backgroundColor = background;
//    [background release];
editController.event =  [eventsList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
editController.eventStore = self.eventStore;
editController.editViewDelegate = self;
itsSelectedReminder = indexPath.row;
isReminderDeleted = TRUE;
[editController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:67/255.0 green:114/255.0 blue:18/255.0 alpha:1]]; 
[self presentModalViewController:editController animated:YES];

[editController release];
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This one drove me nuts for a while, but I finally figured it out.

The trick is to somehow get access to the table view inside the EKEventEditViewController, and there seems to be only one (documented) way to do that:

First, set the view controller presenting the `EKEventEditViewController` (or whatever you want to be responsible for the customization) as a `UINavigationControllerDelegate`:

```
@interface YourViewController : UIViewController <UINavigationControllerDelegate>
```

Second, set your view controller to be the `EKEventEditViewController`'s delegate:

```
EKEventEditViewController *eventEditViewController = [[EKEventEditViewController alloc] init];
eventEditViewController.delegate = yourViewController; // Probably self
```

Third, implement the following method in the delegate:

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated {
    if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[UITableViewController class]]) {
        ((UITableViewController *)viewController).tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        ((UITableViewController *)viewController).tableView.backgroundView = nil;
    }
}
```

This example will change the `EKEventEditViewController`'s table view background to blue, but now that you have access to the actual navigation controller and the table view inside you can do whatever you want!

Note: I have not yet submitted this code to Apple, but I'm not using anything undocumented, so I don't see what would cause an issue.

Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks a lot it is working great..  How ever if I click Title/Location inside still I see the old default screen.  Can you help me to change that background..